# Problem when linking code - how to find reference?

Tags: compiling, ld

I have a problem building some applications from source (here it is freecad). Kubuntu 20.04

When linking there are error messages (the missing reference does vary)

`` /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: undefined reference to `gnutls_srp_set_client_credentials@GNUTLS_3_4 ``

When I check the library

```
readelf -sW /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 | grep gnutls_srp_set
   191: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gnutls_srp_set_client_credentials@GNUTLS_3_4 (6)
```

the reference is there.

Any hint what I am (or ld is) missing here?

Update: Libs, that come with Filezilla Client created the same error messages on my Ubuntu server. I filed a bug report there under
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/12426#ticket

Comment: I think the UND is undefined, so you are probably missing a link library.

Comment: Then use `sudo apt-get install freecad` .

Comment: Can I find out with link library is missing?
I tried to compile freecad because the apt-version does not work with a similar error message. I managed to get git running again that way.

Comment: Undefined seems to be right, but the reference is on the system ```readelf -sW ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep srp_set_client
   877: 000000000009dab0   174 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 gnutls_srp_set_client_credentials@@GNUTLS_3_4
```